# Views block visibility

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms, blocks

I want to show the block only on this page `/category` and not show on every next like `/category?page=1`

As I see it's a big problem for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the visibility of a block in the block page (admin/structure/block).
In the visibility tab select 'Show for the listed pages' and in the 'Pages' just add /category. Use /category/* to display the block in all the pages.